# JSoup: no instances of type variables exist so that String conforms to Element

Tags: java-8, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to parse a webpage.

This is my code:

```
List<Element> nodes = inodes.stream()
                    .filter(n -> n.child(0).text().contains("hello"))
                    .map(n -> n.data())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
        equality constraints: Element
    lower bounds: String
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>toList()
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`Element.data` return type is `String`, so `collect` return type should be `List<String>`, like:

```
List<String> nodes = inodes.stream()
                    .filter(n -> n.child(0).text().contains("hello"))
                    .map(n -> n.data())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```